# Is it possible to assign a value of a variable, print, and provide input in one line?

Tags: python

I want to let the user input a value like... Fruit 1 of 4: (input).. however, the prompt shows in the next line.

```
print("Fruit ", i+1, "of ", numF, ": ")
selF = input()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the text in `input(..)`:

```
selF = input("Fruit %s of %s" % (i+1, numF))
```

Or use:

```
selF = input("Fruit {0} of {1}".format(i+1, numF))
```

Or if python version higher or equal to 3.6, you can use:

```
selF = input(f"Fruit {i+1} of {numF}")
```

Comment: How to accept? Sorry, I'm just new here in Stackoverflow

Comment: @June https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done clicking the check icon :)